# Swift 3 - ImagePickerController circular editor?

Tags: swift, swift3, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

[Here is a image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Q8u.png)

Below is an action from a UIAlertController that displays the ImagePickerController

```
let chooseFromLibrary = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Library", style: .default) { (action) in
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Below is the code that saves the original or selected image.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker {
        userPhotoImgView.image = selectedImage
    }
```